# How to fix braking problem

Tags: road-bike

My Shimano BR-Z57 front side pull brakes. Don't brake smoothly and jerks under braking. Does anyone have any suggestions on why & how to fix this problem?

Comment: Could be several things, though worn-out or dried-out brake pads are the first guess.

Comment: There isn't much here to go on; perhaps you could make it more likely to get an answer by adding a photo?

Answer (score 2):

Possible issues (probably not a complete list - things I've seen)

- Dirty rims - if the rim does not provide a consistent friction surface (there is dirt that makes one part too sticky or too slick - brake pad residue etc.) you will not get smooth braking.
- Dents or blips in the rim - if the rim is wider or dented in some places it will affect braking smoothness.
- Dirty brake pads - may not affect smooth braking but clean pads will improve general braking.

I'm sure others will have suggestions.

Comment: Point 3, not just dirty brake pads, but old ones go hard over time and produce some horrific grab/release pulsing   This brake dates from the mid 1980s so it could easily have old pads.      Point 2, an untrue rim will feel weird while braking because the caliper has to swing left and right to track it.   Also if the rims are as old as the brakes, they could be steel.